# Php mysql update fila sin unique o primary key

Tags: php, mysql

No sabía que había esta página en Español, la verdad que mi experiencia en la página en inglés ha sido absolutamente penosa por no decir otra cosa, para una simple pregunta que resumo a continuación.

En una base de datos que pongo de ejemplo, ya sé que existen muchas versiones, *MariaDb*, etc., pero no es el caso. Cuando corremos el `loop` o bucle `while` se generan lo que es la lectura de los datos por columnas específicas, etc., y vemos que los valores se muestran como se han guardado en la base de datos, en los ejemplos que pongo vemos que las filas se pueden clasificar con un `id` interno de bucle como pongo en los ejemplos, es algo parecido a lo que puede pasar con las bases de datos típicas y sencillas en un archivo de texto, sin más.

El caso es que yo puedo perfectamente hacer un `update` seleccionando la fila y cambiar el valor que quiero, y el caso es que el `script` funciona pero se presentan problemas cuando tengo una simple base de datos sin una ***unique key*** o sin ***primary key***, imaginemos una simple base de datos para poner lo que me de la gana sin más y en donde hay muchos datos y muchos repetidos, por ejemplo como en mi caso el color.

Por todo ello si un valor, como pongo en el ejemplo, se repite, no se cambia solo el valor de una fila sino de todas las filas donde ese valor se repite, el caso es cómo se puede hacer para que a pesar de haber valores repetidos y de no tener ***unique key*** o ***primary keys***, puedo editar una columna específica y editarla sin afectar a las demás, que si quiero cambiar el color rojo a verde de la fila 7 no se cambia en toda las demás porque he seleccionado una columna que tiene el mismo valor y que al no ser ***unique key***, etc., hará un `update` general de todas las columnas con el mismo valor.

**Script clásico para mostrar datos :**

```
$query=mysql_query('select * from test',$connect->connect_db());

$num_row=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

echo $row['colors'];

$num_row++;
}
```

**Cambiar datos de una fila específica :**

```
$query=mysql_query('select * from test',$connect->connect_db());
        
$num_row=0;
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
        
if($num_row==7)
{
mysql_query("update test set list_colors='red' where list_colors='green'", $connect->connect_db());
}
        
$num_row++;
}
```

Esa sería en definitiva mi pregunta, como poder seleccionar una fila específica que el `script` lo hace y también cambia los valores, pero con la especificación, de que no use ***unique key*** o no use ***primary key***, esa sería la cuestión, gracias.

Comment: En este caso no hay filas específicas como tales, no existe la fila 7 porque no hay ningún indice (primary key) con el que puedas apuntarla.  Tan solo puedes hacer cambios poniendo en el where exactamente los valores de todas las columnas coincidentes con el registro que quieras cambiar, y si este esta repetido entonces se cambiaran todos

Comment: Si eso comprobé, entonces digamos que no hay forma de evitar cambiar todos los valores coincidentes y solo editar el de la fila en cuestion, he leido algo de num rows o similar o acotar el número de filas a editar con el mismo valor con Limit no se si eso pudiese servir, saludos

Comment: La respuesta que da @Brutangex podria servirte, pero no veo mucha diferencia entre eso y una primary key tambien incremental... ¿por que motivo no usas una primary key?  ¿que te lleva a pensar que eso es mejor que usar una?

Comment: Mi pregunta viene a raiz de tablas que están llenas de datos y que no poseen primary key o unique key solo datos, con columnas que poseen datos repetidos, elscript que pongo funciona solo qeu cuando la columna tiene un dato repetido pues altera todas, por eso si había alguna forma de hacer como en un flat file y cambiar solo los datos de una específica fila alestilo de cuando se recorre un bucle de un flat file y se cambia sola esa linea sin afectar a las demas

Comment: Bueno, es que esa linea da igual donde este, en todo caso podrias probar con LIMIT en tu consulta de UPDATE, pero al no tener ningún tipo de índice quizás se modifica la que no te piensas, pero en el fondo da igual, todas las demas son iguales.